# "Export" core-data with Magical Record

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm using Magical Record and love the "import" functions.

Is there a similar "export" function that will generate JSON compatible objects using the same field name mapping?

i.e.

If I have JSON with a field "id" I can map it to the field "objectID" so that the import will auto create "objectID".

Can I export the object with "objectID" and generate a dictionary with a key "id".

Comment: can you send link how to use import function? because I also try to find out the best way how to mapping data object with json. Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Easymapping can do that. 
Take it here https://github.com/lucasmedeirosleite/EasyMapping